# Equivalent of "passwd -sa" in RHEL?

Tags: linux, rhel, password

I feel a little silly having to ask this, but: In Solaris you can issue a `passwd -sa` command which gives you (more or less) the same output as `passwd -S userName` does, except it prints out the status information for all users it finds in /etc/passwd. What is the equivalent GNU/Linux command?

I'm trying to put together simple instructions for someone else to baseline a server, and part of that is them identifying the password aging configured on all accounts. I can for loop over `cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd` but I was hoping there was a simple command I could give him.

Comment: The `cut` method seems reasonable and safe to me.

Comment: there's always `chage -l <user>`, looping through the `/etc/passwd` 8-).

Answer (score 2):

In RHEL/CentOS there is no `-a` option with passwd but `-S` option is there. So you run this one liner as root user:

```
  for user in `awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd`; do passwd -S $user; done
```

or

```
  for user in $(awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd); do passwd -S $user; done
```

Answer (score 1):

At least in shadow-utils 4.1.5.1 on Arch Linux, I have `-a`, which also prints the status. `passwd -Sa` appears to do what you want. From `man passwd`:

```
   -a, --all
       This option can be used only with -S and causes show status for all users.
   -S, --status
       Display account status information. The status information consists
       of 7 fields. The first field is the user's login name. The second
       field indicates if the user account has a locked password (L), has
       no password (NP), or has a usable password (P). The third field
       gives the date of the last password change. The next four fields
       are the minimum age, maximum age, warning period, and inactivity
       period for the password. These ages are expressed in days.
```

```
# passwd -Sa
root P 05/07/2013 -1 -1 -1 -1
bin P 09/19/2010 -1 -1 -1 -1
daemon P 09/19/2010 -1 -1 -1 -1
mail P 09/19/2010 -1 -1 -1 -1
ftp P 09/19/2010 -1 -1 -1 -1
http P 09/19/2010 -1 -1 -1 -1
uuidd P 09/19/2010 -1 -1 -1 -1
dbus P 09/19/2010 -1 -1 -1 -1
nobody P 09/19/2010 -1 -1 -1 -1
git L 05/07/2013 -1 -1 -1 -1
chris P 05/07/2013 0 99999 7 -1
avahi L 05/07/2013 -1 -1 -1 -1
mpd L 05/07/2013 -1 -1 -1 -1
ntp L 05/07/2013 0 99999 7 -1
nullmail L 05/13/2013 -1 -1 -1 -1
polkitd L 05/14/2013 0 99999 7 -1
```

Comment: :\ Well it looks like RHEL uses a different software package for the passwd command (`passwd-0.77-4.el6_2.2.x86_64`) and the shadow-utils that is included (`shadow-utils-4.1.4.2-13.el6.x86_6`) doesn't have a passwd command.

Comment: @JoelDavis could be a permissions/path issue, can you run `passwd -Sa` as `root`?

Comment: Sorry, I guess my response was a bit ambiguous, the `-a` option isn't available with the version of `passwd` I'm using

Comment: None of the versions of RH distros I have (Fedora or CentOS 5&6) have a `-a` switch.